# PHP is generating multiple sessions

Tags: php, session

I am not sure what is at fault here, but I have tried literally everything to resolve a very annoying issue that has plagued my site now constantly, and that is PHP generating multiple sessions per user.

At the moment, I am the only person using the site, so I know fully well there is no possibility of someone else creating a session, however, to be sure, I stored the IP Address immediately after initiating session_start() within my session class.. and low and behold, it is my IP Address being generated constantly. After I log in, there is then 5 or 6 more records been added into the database, each containing my IP Address, with only one with the session information.

Now, the website works fine, however I know for a fact this isn't normal behavior. I am only calling session_start() once, I have not called regenerate_id anywhere on the site apart from logging in, however even before logging in three records are added as soon as I visit the site.

I am wondering if this is a known issue, and also if anyone could comb through my code and see if they can see anything that may be causing this odd behavior, because unfortunately a good hour or so on Google and searching SO hasn't cropped up much of a result (apart from unanswered questions with the save issue)

```
class Sessions {

private $life_time, $database;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->life_time = DatabaseConfig::read('SESSION_MAX_LIFETIME'); // Set within a config file, returns 1440
    $this->database = DatabaseCore::getInstance(); // Basically allows me to create only one instance of the database to avoid overhead from multiple persistent connections.

    session_set_save_handler( 
        array( &$this, "NewSession" ), 
        array( &$this, "CloseSession" ),
        array( &$this, "ReadSession" ),
        array( &$this, "WriteSession"),
        array( &$this, "DestroySession"),
        array( &$this, "CleanSessions" )
    );

    session_name("SESSION_GEEK_PANEL"); 
    session_start();
}

public function NewSession( $save_path, $session_name ) {

    $sess_save_path = $save_path;

    return true;

}

public function ReadSession( $id ) {

    $sth = $this->database->dbh->prepare("SELECT `session_data` FROM `sessions` WHERE `session_id` = :session_id ");
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':session_id'    => $id
    ));

    if( $sth->rowCount() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $sth->fetch();
        $data = $row['session_data'];
    }

    return $data;

}

public function WriteSession( $id, $data ) {

    $sth = $this->database->dbh->prepare("REPLACE `sessions` (`session_id`, `session_data`, `expires`) VALUES( :id, :data, :expires )");

    $sth->execute(array(
        ':id'    => $id,
        ':data' => $data,
        ':expires' => time() + $this->life_time
    ));

    return true;

}

public function DestroySession( $id ) {

    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );

    $sth = $this->database->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `session_id` = :id");
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':id' => $id
    ));

    return true;

}

public function CleanSessions() {

    $sth = $this->database->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `expires` < :time");
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':time' => time()
    ));

    return true;

}

public function CloseSession() {

    return true;

}
}
DatabaseConfig::write('SESSION_MAX_LIFETIME', MAX_SESSION_LIFE);
```

All help is greatly appreciated, finally.. could this be a fault with the host or PHP INI file? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked session.auto_start in PHP INI?